# How to specify clientid in a soap envelope?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

This code doesn't work.  It say the customer key (triggered send) doesn't exist. If I use a user that has access to that particular business unit only then this code works.

```
<soap:Body>
<api:CreateRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:api="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <api:Options>
                                <api:Client>
                                                <api:ClientID>98989</api:ClientID>
                                </api:Client>
                </api:Options>
                <api:Objects xsi:type="api:TriggeredSend">
                                <api:TriggeredSendDefinition>
                                                <api:CustomerKey>Test_SGH_Order_Cancel_TS</api:CustomerKey>
                                </api:TriggeredSendDefinition>
                                <api:Subscribers>
                                                <api:EmailAddress>XXXX@salesforce.com</api:EmailAddress>
                                                <api:SubscriberKey>XXXX@salesforce.com</api:SubscriberKey>
                                                <api:Attributes>
                                                                <api:Name>FROMEMAILADDRESS</api:Name>
                                                                <api:Value>XXX@XXX.com</api:Value>
                                                </api:Attributes>
                                                <api:Attributes>
                                                                <api:Name>TransactionID</api:Name>
                                                                <api:Value>S23232</api:Value>
                                                </api:Attributes>
                                                <api:Attributes>
                                                                <api:Name>OrderID</api:Name>
                                                                <api:Value>SDJUEM</api:Value>
                                                </api:Attributes>
                                                <api:Attributes>
                                                                <api:Name>EmailType</api:Name>
                                                                <api:Value>E</api:Value>
                                                </api:Attributes>

                </api:Subscribers>
        </api:Objects>
</api:CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: This is expected - the client ID you specifiy, would be a business unit and only a user that has access to that business unit would be able to operate on it.

Comment: Correct.  But in this scenario the user has access to the correct Business Unit and a few other Business Units and if specify the business unit id in the soap request shouldn't it know where to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the `client` object into the create request, and change `clientId` (depracated) to `ID`.

```
<soap:Body>
  <api:CreateRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:api="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <api:Objects xsi:type="api:TriggeredSend">
      <api:Client>
        <api:ID>98989</api:ID>
      </api:Client>
      <api:TriggeredSendDefinition>
        <api:CustomerKey>Test_SGH_Order_Cancel_TS</api:CustomerKey>
      </api:TriggeredSendDefinition>
      <api:Subscribers>
        <api:EmailAddress>XXXX@salesforce.com</api:EmailAddress>
        <api:SubscriberKey>XXXX@salesforce.com</api:SubscriberKey>
        <api:Attributes>
          <api:Name>FROMEMAILADDRESS</api:Name>
          <api:Value>XXX@XXX.com</api:Value>
        </api:Attributes>
        <api:Attributes>
          <api:Name>TransactionID</api:Name>
          <api:Value>S23232</api:Value>
        </api:Attributes>
        <api:Attributes>
          <api:Name>OrderID</api:Name>
          <api:Value>SDJUEM</api:Value>
        </api:Attributes>
        <api:Attributes>
          <api:Name>EmailType</api:Name>
          <api:Value>E</api:Value>
        </api:Attributes>
      </api:Subscribers>
    </api:Objects>
  </api:CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```